Assertion Error while writing tests for SQLAlchemy code in Python
I'm trying to write some tests for a function, but I'm hitting some roadblocks.
The function that I'm trying to test has the following code:
async def delete_client_from_group(group_id: int, client_id: int, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
result = await db.execute(select(Group).filter(Group.group_id == group_id))
group = await (await result.scalars()).first()
if group is None:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Group not found")

result = await db.execute(select(Client).filter(Client.client_id == client_id))
client = await (await result.scalars()).first()
if not client:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Client not found")

result = await db.execute(
    select(ClientGroupAssociation).filter(ClientGroupAssociation.group_id == group_id,
                                          ClientGroupAssociation.client_id == client_id)
)
existing_association = await (await result.scalars()).first()

if not existing_association:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Client is not in the group")

await db.delete(existing_association)
await db.commit()

return {"detail": "Client removed from group successfully"}

I've tried writing this test:
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_delete_client_from_group_success():

# Create mock AsyncSession
mock_db = AsyncMock(spec=AsyncSession)

# Mock the objects to be returned by the queries
mock_group = MagicMock(spec=Group)
mock_client = MagicMock(spec=Client)
mock_association = MagicMock(spec=ClientGroupAssociation)

# Mock the return values of the database queries
async def mock_execute(statement, *args, **kwargs):
    if str(select(Group).filter(Group.group_id == 1)) == str(statement):
        scalars_mock = AsyncMock()
        scalars_mock.first.return_value = mock_group
        return AsyncMock(scalars=scalars_mock)
    elif str(select(Client).filter(Client.client_id == 1)) == str(statement):
        scalars_mock = AsyncMock()
        scalars_mock.first.return_value = mock_client
        return AsyncMock(scalars=scalars_mock)
    elif str(select(ClientGroupAssociation).filter(
            ClientGroupAssociation.group_id == 1,
            ClientGroupAssociation.client_id == 1)) == str(statement):
        scalars_mock = AsyncMock()
        scalars_mock.first.return_value = mock_association
        return AsyncMock(scalars=scalars_mock)
    return None

# Set up the mock_db.execute side effect
mock_db.execute.side_effect = mock_execute

# Mock the delete and commit methods
mock_db.delete = AsyncMock()
mock_db.commit = AsyncMock()

# Call the function being tested
response = await delete_client_from_group(group_id=1, client_id=1, db=mock_db)

# Ensure the correct association object was deleted
mock_db.delete.assert_called_once_with(mock_association)

# Ensure the commit was called
mock_db.commit.assert_called_once()

# Check that the response is correct
assert response == {"detail": "Client removed from group successfully"}

But it gives me an Assertion Error, as presented in the following section:
unit_tests\add_client_to_group_test.py:310 (test_delete_client_from_group_success)
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_delete_client_from_group_success():
    # Create mock AsyncSession
    mock_db = AsyncMock(spec=AsyncSession)

    # Mock the objects to be returned by the queries
    mock_group = MagicMock(spec=Group)
    mock_client = MagicMock(spec=Client)
    mock_association = MagicMock(spec=ClientGroupAssociation)

    # Mock the return values of the database queries
    async def mock_execute(statement, *args, **kwargs):
        if str(select(Group).filter(Group.group_id == 1)) == str(statement):
            scalars_mock = AsyncMock()
            scalars_mock.first.return_value = mock_group
            return AsyncMock(scalars=scalars_mock)
        elif str(select(Client).filter(Client.client_id == 1)) == str(statement):
            scalars_mock = AsyncMock()
            scalars_mock.first.return_value = mock_client
            return AsyncMock(scalars=scalars_mock)
        elif str(select(ClientGroupAssociation).filter(
                ClientGroupAssociation.group_id == 1,
                ClientGroupAssociation.client_id == 1)) == str(statement):
            scalars_mock = AsyncMock()
            scalars_mock.first.return_value = mock_association
            return AsyncMock(scalars=scalars_mock)
        return None

    # Set up the mock_db.execute side effect
    mock_db.execute.side_effect = mock_execute

    # Mock the delete and commit methods
    mock_db.delete = AsyncMock()
    mock_db.commit = AsyncMock()

    # Call the function being tested
    response = await delete_client_from_group(group_id=1, client_id=1, db=mock_db)

    # Ensure the correct association object was deleted
>       mock_db.delete.assert_called_once_with(mock_association)

add_client_to_group_test.py:350: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
C:\Users\Rus Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\unittest\mock.py:956: in assert_called_once_with
    return self.assert_called_with(*args, **kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <AsyncMock name='mock.delete' id='1951874194448'>
args = (<MagicMock name='mock.scalars.first()' spec='ClientGroupAssociation' id='1951873591072'>,)
kwargs = {}
expected = call(<MagicMock name='mock.scalars.first()' spec='ClientGroupAssociation' id='1951873591072'>)
actual = call(<AsyncMock name='mock.scalars().first()' id='1951874587904'>)
_error_message = <function NonCallableMock.assert_called_with.<locals>._error_message at 0x000001C674C753A0>
cause = None

    def assert_called_with(self, /, *args, **kwargs):
        """assert that the last call was made with the specified arguments.
    
        Raises an AssertionError if the args and keyword args passed in are
        different to the last call to the mock."""
        if self.call_args is None:
            expected = self._format_mock_call_signature(args, kwargs)
            actual = 'not called.'
            error_message = ('expected call not found.\nExpected: %s\n  Actual: %s'
                    % (expected, actual))
            raise AssertionError(error_message)
    
        def _error_message():
            msg = self._format_mock_failure_message(args, kwargs)
            return msg
        expected = self._call_matcher(_Call((args, kwargs), two=True))
        actual = self._call_matcher(self.call_args)
        if actual != expected:
            cause = expected if isinstance(expected, Exception) else None
>           raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: delete(<MagicMock name='mock.scalars.first()' spec='ClientGroupAssociation' id='1951873591072'>)
E             Actual: delete(<AsyncMock name='mock.scalars().first()' id='1951874587904'>)

I'm at a loss at how to resolve this Assertion Error. Any help is welcome!
